# botocore package in lambda python 3.9 runtime return error: "cannot import name "'DEPRECATED_SERVICE_NAMES'" from 'botocore.docs'"

Tags: python, lambda, boto3

I am using Lambda Python 3.9 runtimes. I also use boto3 and botocore default packages in Lambda.

Today, I suddenly got this error: "cannot import name "'DEPRECATED_SERVICE_NAMES'" from 'botocore.docs'". I only succeeded in fixing it when I added the botocore package to the lambda runtime. I want to avoid it since it increases the size of the layer by 10 MB.

Any help? thanks

Comment: Thanks. I came across this issue today also and resolved it by upgrading `botocore` to the latest available version.

Answer (score 18):

There is an issue with the latest releases of boto3. You can see the issue here: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3648. You need to downgrade boto3 version in your lambda. For this include a lower version of boto3 in your requirements.txt file. For example, boto3==1.26.90 worked for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

There may be an issue with some of the previous versions of boto3.  Upgrading the boto3 version worked for me. In my case, I upgraded from v1.27.59 to v1.31.85.

```
pip install --upgrade boto3
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I fixed it without including boto3 or botocore in the deployment package or layer by rolling back the Lambda runtime to a version that was working previously. From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-update.html#runtime-management-rollback-manual):

> If you're using the **Auto** runtime version update mode, or you're using the `$LATEST` runtime version, you can roll back your runtime version using the **Manual** mode. For the function version you want to roll back, change the runtime version update mode to **Manual** and specify the ARN of the previous runtime version. For more information about finding the ARN of the previous runtime version, see [Identifying runtime version changes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-update.html#runtime-management-identify).

Which says:

> The runtime version number and ARN are logged in the `INIT_START` log line, which Lambda emits to CloudWatch Logs each time that it creates a new [execution environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-concepts.html#gettingstarted-concepts-ee). Because the execution environment uses the same runtime version for all function invocations, Lambda emits the `INIT_START` log line only when Lambda executes the init phase. Lambda doesn't emit this log line for each function invocation. Lambda emits the log line to CloudWatch Logs, but it is not visible in the console.

Their example `INIT_START` log line, which can help you search CloudWatch Logs:

```
INIT_START Runtime Version: python:3.9.v14    Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:eu-south-1::runtime:7b620fc2e66107a1046b140b9d320295811af
```

This is a temporary fix because as long as the runtime management configuration is in Manual mode, the runtime won't receive security or performance updates.

Answer (score -4):

Upgrading `botocore` should solve the problem.

```
pip install --upgrade botocore
```